# Calling only date from datagridview to a textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
        {
            DataGridViewRow row = this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
            textBox3.Text = row.Cells["StartDate"].Value.ToString();
```

I am trying to pass the date data **(Appear as 8/24/2017 in database)** from datagridview to a textbox to display the start date given in the picture below. However the time (12:00:00AM) kept appearing even when the data type is Date and not datetime. May I know what is the solution to the problem here?

[image]

Comment: The data type in the database may well be date, but Net doesn't have a "Date" variable type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if your cell contains value, and if it does, cast it to `DateTime` (since it came from database, there's no need to use parsing).

Take a look at this example

```
if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
{
    DataGridViewRow row = this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    if (row.Cells["StartDate"].Value != null)
    {
        DateTime date = (DateTime) row.Cells["StartDate"].Value;
        //now convert DateTime fo any text format you want to use
        textBox3.Text = date.ToShortDateString();
        //or, you can use some custom format
        //textBox3.Text = date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
        //textBox3.Text = date.ToString("ddd MM/dd/yyyy");
        //etc

    }
}
```

also, take a look at msdn [custom date and time formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)

Comment: Thanks for the help Nino. Works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

You can parse value from the "StartDate" cell into `DateTime` and then use `ToShortDateString()` method to get desired output:

```
var startDate = DateTime.Parse(row.Cells["StartDate"].Value);
var startDateDisplay = startDate.ToShortDateString();
```

Note: Keep in mind that `Parse` method uses Date format from the current culture, so if you have different date format, consider using `TryParse` method instead or one of the `Parse` method overloads in which you'll provide specific format.

Comment: although your answer could be helpful to OP, there's no need to parse DateTime that is fetched from database. Also, null value will throw an exception.